# Best way to expire Cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, global-asax

Here's my code to retrieve all categories, it works well:

```
public static List<Category> GetAllCategories()
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
    using (profiler.Step("GetAllCategories()"))
    {
        if (context.Cache["StoreCategories"] == null)
        {
            var r = new List<Category>();
            using (var db = new MainContext())
            {
                var q = db.v2StoreCategories;
                foreach (var cat in q)
                {
                    r.Add(new Category(cat));
                }
            }
            context.Cache["StoreCategories"] = r;
        }
    }
    return (List<Category>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["StoreCategories"];
}
```

Assuming I need to build in a way to refresh this cache every n minutes, what's the best way to go about this?

Is safe to have a timed event in global.asax that does it?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
```

where applicable.

Make sure you use the right context. ie

```
HttpContext.Current
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `Cache.Insert(...)` method. That way you can provide a time to live for the object in the cache. Something like this:

```
public static List<Category> GetAllCategories()
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
    using (profiler.Step("GetAllCategories()"))
    {
        if (context.Cache["StoreCategories"] == null)
        {
            var r = new List<Category>();
            using (var db = new MainContext())
            {
                var q = db.v2StoreCategories;
                foreach (var cat in q)
                {
                    r.Add(new Category(cat));
                }
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
                "StoreCategories",
                r,
                null,
                DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),  // TTL = one minute in this sample
                TimeSpan.Zero
            );
        }
    }
    return (List<Category>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["StoreCategories"];
}
```

Then the caching framework will automatically remove the object from the cache when it gets old and your method will then recreate it next time it is called.

You can also provide a callback method in `Cache.Insert` which will automatically be called when the cached object expires. The callback can then work in the background to refresh the cached object. That way, a user will not have to wait for the cached object to be built:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
    "StoreCategories",
    r,
    null,
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),
    TimeSpan.Zero,
    UpdateCategoriesCache
);
```

And:

```
private static void UpdateCategoriesCache(
    string key,
    System.Web.Caching.CacheItemUpdateReason reason,
    out Object categories,
    out CacheDependency dependency,
    out DateTime absoluteExpiration,
    out TimeSpan slidingExpiration
)
{
    // fetch categories here
    categories = fetchedCategories;
    dependency = null;
    absoluteExpiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1);
    slidingExpiration = TimeSpan.Zero;
}
```